# Lucene not giving results when specifying field

Tags: lucene, field, pylucene

I have a database which I have indexed in Lucene (using Pylucene) by section (specified by markup in the document) using lucene's fields.  This index seems to work fine.  I can search it using the default field which is simply the entire document and get reasonable results.

The problem is, when I search it using a specific section (not the default), I expect to get a certain number of results back (as specified by `IndexSearcher.search(query, results)`), but instead it might simply return nothing.  So my question is: how can I get it to return a ranked list with the number of results I specify?

The only place I specify the field is in the QueryParser, by calling:

```
QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, field, StandardAnalyzer)
```

Comment: Not giving much to go on here.  Do you have reason to believe you should have that certain number of valid results for it to return?  And was the field you're trying to search actually indexed?

Answer (score 0):

I would verify the index using [Luke](http://code.google.com/p/luke/) (which is something I do often when modifying my index strategy).